# Core Data Merge Policy Sometimes Deletes Objects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, merge

I’m trying to create simple application that has conversations on the left hands side of a a split view, and messages on the right hand side. The conversation list on the left will show each conversations recordID, description, and details of the latest message. The message view has an "Add Messages" button that will simulate adding a message to the conversation. This will always use the same message ID. This is to test the merge policy, which is a NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy. The issue that I am facing is that the latestMessage becomes nil 50% of the time you add a new message. This will cause the application to crash because the conversation list is using the latestMessage property to display the latestMessage details.

I'm looking for a solution to how to effectively show the latestMessage in the conversation list without causing a crash. I would also like to understand what is causing this issue in the first place. My assumption is that it has something to do with the merge policy, but I’m not sure why because all of my other objects respect the merge policy without issue.

All of the necessary code is below. Here is a [link](https://github.com/Rspoon3/Testing) to the project if you wish to download it.

[image: Core Data Relationships]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ConversationsView()
            Text("Select a conversation")
        }
    }
}

struct MessagesView: View{
    @StateObject var model: MessagesModel
    @ObservedObject var conversation: Conversation
    
    init(conversation: Conversation) {
        _model = StateObject(wrappedValue: MessagesModel(conversation: conversation))
        self.conversation = conversation
    }
    
    var body: some View{
        List(model.messages){ message in
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text("ID: \(message.id)")
                Text("Message: \(message.message)")
                Text("Person: \(message.person.firstName)")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Messages \(model.messages.count)")
        .toolbar(content: {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                Button("Add Messages"){
                    model.addMessage(to: conversation)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

struct ConversationsView: View{
    @StateObject var model = ConversationModel()
    
    var body: some View{
        List(model.conversations){ convo in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: MessagesView(conversation: convo),
                label: {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("Record id: \(convo.id)")
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text("Description: \(convo.myDescription)")
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text("\(convo.latestMessage.person.fullName): \(convo.latestMessage.message)")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                })
        }.navigationTitle("Conversations \(model.conversations.count)")
    }
}

class ConversationModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{
    @Published var conversations = [Conversation]()
    private let conversationsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Conversation>
    
    override init(){
        conversationsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: Conversation.getAllConversations(),
                                                             managedObjectContext: PersistentStore.shared.context,
                                                             sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                                             cacheName: nil)
        super.init()
        conversationsController.delegate = self
        
        do {
            try conversationsController.performFetch()
            conversations = conversationsController.fetchedObjects ?? []
            createConversations()
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    private func createConversations(){
        let context = PersistentStore.shared.context
        
        let conversation = Conversation(context: context)
        let ricky        = Person(context: context)
        let message      = Message(context: context)
        
        ricky.firstName = "Ricky"
        ricky.lastName = "W"
        ricky.title = "iOS Dev"
        
        message.id = 1
        message.message = "Testing 123"
        message.timeStamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        message.person = ricky
        
        conversation.myDescription = "This is a conversation"
        conversation.id = 1
        conversation.activeParticipants.insert(ricky)
        conversation.latestMessage = message
        conversation.messages.insert(message)
        
        PersistentStore.shared.saveContext()
    }
    
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        if let items = controller.fetchedObjects as? [Conversation]{
            conversations = items
        }
    }
}

class MessagesModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{
    @Published var messages = [Message]()
    private let messagesController: NSFetchedResultsController<Message>
    
    init(conversation: Conversation){
        messagesController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: Message.getMessagesFor(conversation),
                                                        managedObjectContext: PersistentStore.shared.context,
                                                        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                                        cacheName: nil)
        super.init()
        messagesController.delegate = self
        
        do {
            try messagesController.performFetch()
            messages = messagesController.fetchedObjects ?? []
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        if let items = controller.fetchedObjects as? [Message]{
            messages = items
        }
    }
    
    func addMessage(to conversation: Conversation){
        let context = PersistentStore.shared.context
        
        let tim = Person(context: context)
        tim.firstName = "Tim"
        tim.lastName = "Apple"
        tim.title = "CEO"
        
        let message = Message(context: context)
        message.id = 2
        message.message = "I Am Tim Apple"
        message.timeStamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        message.person = tim
        
        conversation.messages.insert(message)
        conversation.latestMessage = message
        
        PersistentStore.shared.saveContext()
    }
}

class PersistentStore: ObservableObject {
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    
    static let shared = PersistentStore()
    private init() {}
    
    // MARK: - Core Data stack
    let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "CoreDataTesting")
        
        // Enable remote notifications
        guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
            fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to retrieve a persistent store description.")
        }
        
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
            
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        
        return container
    }()
    
    
    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Delete For Debug
    
    func deleteEverythingForDebug(){
        let conversationsRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Conversation")
        let messagesRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>      = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Message")
        let personRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>        = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")

        let conversationsDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: conversationsRequest)
        let messagesDeleteRequest      = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: messagesRequest)
        let personDeleteRequest        = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: personRequest)

        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.execute(conversationsDeleteRequest)
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.execute(messagesDeleteRequest)
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.execute(personDeleteRequest)
            print("Deleted all of Core Data objects.")
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error deleting everything: \(error)")
        }
        
        saveContext()
    }
}


public class Conversation : NSManagedObject, Identifiable{
    @NSManaged public var activeParticipants   : Set<Person>
    @NSManaged public var myDescription        : String
    @NSManaged public var id                   : Int
    @NSManaged public var messages             : Set<Message>
    @NSManaged public var latestMessage        : Message
    
    static func getAllConversations() -> NSFetchRequest<Conversation> {
        let request : NSFetchRequest<Conversation> = Conversation.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Conversation>
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "latestMessage.timeStamp", ascending: false)]
        return request
    }
}



public class Message : NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var id           : Int
    @NSManaged public var message      : String
    @NSManaged public var timeStamp    : Double
    @NSManaged public var person       : Person
    @NSManaged public var conversation : Conversation
    @NSManaged public var latestConversation : Conversation
    
    static func getMessagesFor(_ conversation: Conversation) -> NSFetchRequest<Message> {
        let request : NSFetchRequest<Message> = Message.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Message>
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: true)]
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "conversation == %@", conversation)
        return request
    }
    
    static func getAllMessages() -> NSFetchRequest<Message> {
        let request : NSFetchRequest<Message> = Message.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Message>
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: true)]
        return request
    }
}


public class Person: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var firstName: String
    @NSManaged public var lastName: String
    @NSManaged public var title: String
    @NSManaged public var conversations: Set<Conversation>
    @NSManaged public var messages: Set<Message>
    
    var fullName : String{
        "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
    }
    
    static func getAllPeopleWith(title: String) -> NSFetchRequest<Person> {
        let request : NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Person>
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: false)]
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title == %@", title)
        return request
    }
    
    static func getAllPeople() -> NSFetchRequest<Person> {
        let request : NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Person>
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: false)]
        return request
    }
}
```